# Limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{-x}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!\sqrt{k}}\right)$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt{x}e^{-x}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!\sqrt{k}}\right)$$
Any hint will be appreciated.

Note: There is a related question on MathOverflow: [Asymptotic expansion of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!{\sqrt{n}}}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/264595). The MO question references this question and it also links to some other posts containing similar expressions.

Comment: Just to let you know, \sum will give you a nicely-formatted $\sum$ symbol that deals with things appearing underneath and above it without any extra effort.

Comment: write $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}e^{-kq^2}dq$ the sum then becomes simple and the remaining integral can be approximated by standard methods

Comment: I tried you way，then it becomes $\sqrt{x}e^{-x}\sum_{k＝1}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-kq^{2}}dq)\frac{x^{k}}{k!}$.How to deal with this one?

Comment: the sum becomes trivial...

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}...=e^{xe^{-y^2}}-1$

Comment: @tired Are you sure that this works?  How does one estimate the integral $\int_0^\infty (e^{xe^{-y^2}}-1)\,dy$ for large $x$?  I don't believe Laplace's method works directly, but perhaps deforming the integration path and applying the method of steepest decent works.  I have not pursued.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: @Dr.MV one can for example integrate by parts to get an integral which is bette suited for the Laplace method. Otherwise a matched asymptotic expansion also works (after some substitutions)

Comment: strange, no work shown so much upvotes. everybody gets downvoted

Comment: @Arjang maybe because this is an interesting problem? but in principle you are right, that is the reason why i resist to write up an answer and only give some hints

Comment: A [discussion on meta which](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31176/does-reputation-change-if-an-answer-gets-deleted-due-to-deletion-of-original-pos) is (to some extent) related to this post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(I have overwritten my previous incorrect answer.)*

For any positive constant $c > 1$ we have: \begin{align*}S(cx) = e^{-x}\sum\limits_{k \ge cx} \frac{x^k}{k!} &= e^{-x}\frac{x^{cx}}{(cx)!}\left(1 + \frac{x}{(cx+1)} + \frac{x^2}{(cx+1)(cx+2)} + \cdots\right) \\& \le e^{-x}\frac{x^{cx}}{(cx)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{c^k} < \frac{c}{c-1}e^{-x}x^{cx}\frac{e^{cx}}{(cx)^{cx}} = \frac{ce^{-((c\log c) -c +1)x}}{c-1}\end{align*}

where, we used the inequality, $x! > e^{-x}x^{x}$ for sufficiently large $x$. Also note that $(c\log c) - c + 1 > 0$ for all $c > 0$

Again, for sufficiently large $x$: \begin{align*}T(x/c) = e^{-x}\sum\limits_{0 \le k < x/c} \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^{-x}\sum\limits_{0 \le k < x/c} \frac{c^k(x/c)^k}{k!} & \le e^{-x}\frac{(x/c)^{x/c}}{(x/c)!}\sum\limits_{0 \le k < x/c} c^k \\& < e^{-x}e^{x/c}\frac{xc^{x/c}}{c} = \frac{x}{c}e^{-\left(1 - \frac{1}{c} - \frac{\log c}{c}\right)x}\end{align*} where, we note that $(1 - \frac{1}{c} - \frac{\log c}{c}) > 0$.

Hence, we have for any $c>1$, $$\displaystyle e^{-x}\sum\limits_{x/c \le k \le cx} \frac{x^k}{k!} = 1 - S(cx) - T(x/c) \quad  \underbrace{\longrightarrow}_{ x \to +\infty} \quad 1 \tag{1}$$

Now, we have the simple estimates, $$\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{cx}}\sum\limits_{x/c \le k \le cx} \frac{x^k}{k!} < e^{-x}\sum\limits_{x/c \le k \le cx} \frac{x^k}{k!\sqrt{k}} < \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x/c}}\sum\limits_{x/c \le k \le cx} \frac{x^k}{k!} \tag{2}$$

and $$e^{-x}\sum\limits_{k \not\in [x/c,cx]} \frac{x^k}{k!\sqrt{k}} < T(x/c) + S(cx) \tag{3}$$ where, both the terms in the upper bound decays exponentially.

Hence, from $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$ we have that the required limit: $$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x}e^{-x}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!\sqrt{k}} \in \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}},\sqrt{c}\right)$$ for arbitrary $c > 1$, i.e., the required limit is $1$ (as pointed out by user **tired** in the comments).

*I suppose* for any function $\alpha(x)$ with atmost polynomial growth and continuous at $x = 1$ we can slightly modify the above argument and show, $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} e^{-x}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha\left(\frac{k}{x}\right)\frac{x^k}{k!} = \alpha(1)$$

Comment: It's nice to see you've returned.  And (+1)  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks! :-)

Comment: Just curious ... How does one justify the inequality $$e^{-x}\sum_{j\ge 1 }\frac1{\sqrt{j}} \sum_{k>j}\frac{x^k}{k!}\le \sum_{j\ge 1 }\frac1{\sqrt{j}} \sum_{k>j}\frac{1}{k!}$$

Comment: Also, I have $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}\sum_{k=j+1}^\infty \frac1{k!}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1{k!}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} \le \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1{k!}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}(1)=1$$which is tighter than the bound you referenced.  How did you obtain it?

Comment: @Dr. MV i think the correct limit is one

Comment: @tired Do you mean that this solution is in error?  I haven't been able to justify the one estimate I referenced.

Comment: @Dr.MV
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}dy(e^{xe^{y^2}}-1)=x\int_0^{\infty}dyy^2e^{-y^2}e^{xe^{-y^2}}=x\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{\infty}dyy^{2n+2}e^{xe^{-y^2}}\sim xe^{x} \sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{\infty}dyy^{2n+2}(e^{-xy^2}+x\mathcal{O}(y^4))\sim xe^{x}\int_{0}^{\infty}dy(y^2+\mathcal{O}(y^4))e^{-xy^2}(1+\mathcal{xO(y^4)})=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{e^{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\left(1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)
$$

from which i conclude that the limit is $1$

Comment: @Dr.MV sorry if there are some mistakes (it is three o'clock in the morning here) but the general reasonig should be correct

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(e%5E(-20)Sqrt%5B20%5D)*Sum%5B20%5Ek%2F(k!+Sqrt%5Bk%5D),%7Bk,1,2000%7D%5D

Comment: @Dr.MV i'm also happy for any feedback..this one is thougher then i thought ;)

Comment: @r9m it is strongly suggested by numerical experiments (and a semiheuristic argument of mine) that the correct limit is $1$. Nevertheless (+1) for the intersting technique

Comment: @r9m I don't believe that $e^{-x}x^k$ is bounded by $1$ for each $k>j$, is it?  Fix $x$ and surely for $k$ large enough, $x^k>e^x$

Comment: @Dr.MV You are right .. :( God knows how I missed that .. I'll try to fix the argument.

Comment: @tired I have edited my answer, hopefully I didn't *screw up* again! :-)