# What's the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}\frac{n^x}{n!}$ with $x$ a positive real number?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, bell-numbers

By the ratio test the series
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{n^x}{n!}
$$
is convergent, but I know no method to evaluate it.

Since it's a convergent series then my question here is:

> Is there a closed form for $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n^x}{n!}$ with $x$ a positive real number?

Comment: For the case when $x$ is a natural number, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/44131/1242).

Comment: If $x\not\in\mathbb{N}$, it is a fractional [Touchard polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials) evaluated at $1$. Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547219/mathematical-infinite-series-closed-form  and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402633/how-does-this-series-scale/2402646#2402646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think, that there is a closed form. The question should be changed to: "What interesting features does this series have (e.g. what integral representations are known) ?"

*A note:*

Be $\enspace\displaystyle f_{N,x}(z):= \sum\limits_{n=0}^N {\binom{N}{n}}n^x z^n\enspace $ with $\,x\geq 0\,$ , $\,z\in\mathbb{C}\,$ and $\,N\in\mathbb{N}_0\,$  .

It follows $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^x}{n!} = \lim\limits_{N\to\infty} f_{N,x}(\frac{1}{N})  \,$ .

For $\enspace x\in\mathbb{N}\enspace$ we have  $\enspace\displaystyle f_{N,x}(z)  = Nz(z+1)^{N-x}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1}z^k \sum\limits_{v=0}^k {\binom{x-N}{k-v}}{\binom{N-1}{v}}(v+1)^{x-1}$

and we see that we get troubles generalizing (e.g) this to real $\,x> 0\,$ .

*A hint* $\,$ for $\,x\in\mathbb{N}\,$ :

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n n^x}{n!} = \lim\limits_{N\to\infty} f_{N,x}(\frac{z}{N}) =$

$\enspace\displaystyle = \lim\limits_{N\to\infty}  (1+\frac{z}{N})^{N-x} z \lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{x-1}(\frac{z}{N})^k \sum\limits_{v=0}^k {\binom{x-N}{k-v}}{\binom{N-1}{v}}(v+1)^{x-1}$

$\enspace\displaystyle =e^z \sum\limits_{k=0}^{x} S_{x,k} z^k\enspace$ 
with the Stirling numbers of the $2^{nd}$ kind $\,\displaystyle S_{x,k}:= \sum\limits_{v=0}^k \frac{(-1)^{k-v} v^x}{(k-v)!v!}\,$ .

The (first) series and the last sum of the equation chain are equal also for $\,x=0\,$ and $\,0^0:=1\,$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer because i don't got any help from above comments , i think this series will make a sense when x is a complex variable

Comment: @zeraouliarafik :  It doesn't change anything, if you use $x$ as a complex variable. But the formula for $f_{N,x}(z)$ leads to the (non-trivial) formula for $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^x z^n}{n!}$ if $x\in\mathbb{N}$ . Because of this it's possible to see, which problem we have, if $x$ isn't a positive integer.

Comment: you are right ! my question In Mo has been reached ,then if you want to share this question in MO i'm agree probably we will find who give us enough informuation for this non-trivial formula

Comment: @zeraouliarafik : As *Jack D'Aurizio* has mentioned, you can discuss the *Touchard polynomials* with real index, maybe you can construct an approximation. *And:* With my answer I just wanted to put a more elementary view on the series which helps to understand, why the existence of a closed form is very unlikely.